# How to count the frequency of elements in a unsorted string-list in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x

This code use List Comprehension what is inefficent.

```
l = ['banana', 'apple', 'linux', 'pie', 'banana', 'win', 'apple', 'banana']
d = {e:l.count(e) for e in l}
d
{'pie': 1, 'linux': 1, 'banana': 3, 'apple': 2, 'win': 1}
```

What would be a better way to count the strings in this unsorted list without loosing the connectino between the string and its count?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> l = ['banana', 'apple', 'linux', 'pie', 'banana', 'win', 'apple', 'banana']
>>> Counter(l)
Counter({'banana': 3, 'apple': 2, 'pie': 1, 'win': 1, 'linux': 1})
```